# Sorting lists (global vs local)

Tags: list

In my application users have lists. They can either add a new item to their list or add an item from a previous list. The set of all items I'll call G (global) (each user's global list is their own).

G = { a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>}

After (or during) a user has created a list they can sort it. This has been no problem. The problem happens when try to apply an items order globally. For example, if list one has m items:

L<sub>1</sub> = {b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>,...,b<sub>m</sub>}

And the user changes the order of b<sub>1</sub> from 1 to 9 in L<sub>1</sub>. Then when the user saves the list I'd like its global order to change as well. But I'm not sure what to change it to.

Here's how I'm doing this now. Take our list L<sub>1</sub>:

L<sub>1</sub> = {**b<sub>1</sub>**, b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>,...,b<sub>m</sub>}

Move b<sub>1</sub>:

L<sub>1</sub> = {b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>, **b<sub>1</sub>**,...,b<sub>m</sub>}

Find out the global index of b<sub>3</sub> (say 41), add one (42) and that's b<sub>1</sub>'s index. Then find all other items that have a global index greater than or equal to 42 and add one.

What's the best (or at least better) way to do this?

Comment: Why not store each user list as a list item in the global list?

Comment: Could you expand on how that would benefit me?

Comment: You haven't describe how you build the global list or its relationship to the local list. Storing the local list as a list would let you rebuild the global index very quickly. This will depend on how many users you have. You will probably find that storing this in a database is the most efficient for performance reasons.

Comment: Ahh, okay. The global list is created once the user creates their first list. When there is only one list then that effectively is the global list. I do store both the list and the global list. I may have not used the correct term. Each user has a global list. Maybe I should have used the term Master List.

Comment: Pretend I know absolutely nothing about your application. How would you describe to be what the global/master list is and how the individual lists are used to make it? Not the processes involved, but a functional description.

Comment: Let's say it's a shopping list. The first week you put apples, oatmeal and pasta on the list, in that order. After thinking about it you resort the list because you usually get apples last. So you have oatmeal, pasta and apples, in that order. The second week you also put apples, oatmeal and pasta on the list, in that order. But when you put them on the list then are automatically resorted to oatmeal, pasta, and apples. The purpose of the global list is to remember an items order when a new list is created. Users will never actually see the global list.

Comment: What happens when the user adds cereal, bread, milk, and peanut butter as a new list? Do those get appended to the global list? And what happens if the user re-orders the list some other way, in the process adding apples?

Comment: If all items on a new list are new they are appended. If there is an existing item with 10 new items the new ones sorted off that existing one. I'm not sure what your second question is.